# How to correctly display a method?

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x

My program is to display the name and type of animal from a list and then randomly choose a feeling.  I can get the first 2 to display properly but the feeling is displaying as: < bound method Animal.get_mood of < Animal.Animal object at 0x105cdf940>> and I can't figure out why any help would be great!

```
for item in animals:
    print(item.get_name(), "the", item.get_animal_type(), "is", item.get_mood())

def __init__(self,animal_type, name, mood = None):
    self.__mood = mood if mood else self.get_mood
def set_mood(self, mood):
    self.__mood = mood

def check_mood(self):
    integer = random.randint(1,3)
    if integer == 1:
        self.__mood = "happy"
    elif integer == 2:
        self.__mood = "hungry"
    elif integer == 3:
        self.__mood = "sleepy"
def get_mood(self):
    return self.__mood
```

Comment: You need to call `get_mood` like this `mood if mood else self.get_mood()` Note the `()` after `get_mood`

Comment: I just did that and I received this long Traceback (most recent call last):
generator/Animal.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.__mood = mood if mood else self.get_mood()
   line 40, in get_mood
    return self.__mood
AttributeError: 'Animal' object has no attribute '_Animal__mood'

Answer (score 2):

Since your get_mood() method returns self.__mood, you can't use it to initialize self.__mood - doing so refers to a variable that doesn't exist yet. Looks like you might want to be calling check_mood() in init, instead. Remember the "()" to indicate that you're calling the method, rather than setting self.__mood equal to the method, as thefourtheye pointed out in comments.

EDIT: Because check_mood() doesn't actually return anything, you need to break it up into an if/else statement as shown below. Alternately, you could make check_mood() return the new mood.

Here's what the fixed init function should look like:

```
def __init__(self,animal_type, name, mood = None):
    if mood:
        self.__mood = mood
    else:
        self.check_mood()
```

Comment: I'm just getting ___ the ____ is None now is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: What line is that occurring on? Or better yet, could you post the full code that you're using? I can't replicate that problem from just what you have here.

Comment: Sample Output:                                                                                         Animal List
------------
Rex the dog is None   Which I think is caused by the mood = None but dont know how to go without that

Comment: Oh, I think I see the problem - check_mood() doesn't actually return anything, so setting self.__mood equal to its return will make self.__mood be None. I edited my answer to fix this.